# Angular js watch on function - identify if the function has been ran

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an Angular app.

I have a service and when i click on a button - the service is running its method.

I would like to watch on the running function. The function itself only init number to 0. 
The number can be zero or not but on a click we will init it.

1. I use the watch, but when the method is running, the watch is not working. 
   It is working only when the app is uploaded. I don't know what I'm doing wrong.
2. One more question, is there a way to differ between old and new values in the watcher regarding the function. It returns me the same function twice.

I would like to know it in order to run the watcher only if the function is running.

The code:

The service with the function:

```
app.service('Service', [function () {

    this.number = 0;

    this.resetNumber = function () {
            this.number = 0;
    };

}]);
```

The click in the html:

```
 <li ng-click="service.resetNumber()">
```

The controller:

```
app.controller('Controller', ['$scope','Service',  
                    function ($scope,Service) {

  $scope.service = Service;

  $scope.$watch('service.resetNumber', function(newValue, oldValue){
        //Do Some Logic
    });
}]);
```

Comment: Where do you change the function?

Comment: What do you mean change the function? The number variable is changing in the app and when i click on the button. I would like to know that the function is running.

Comment: In your code you `$watch` the `resetNumber` function, so you want to know about changes of the **function** itself. If you want to be notified about the changes of the number, you must `$watch` the `number` variable instead of function.

Comment: I know this. I would like to know when i enter to this function.

Comment: I'm trying to understand your use case. You want to get notified each time the `resetNumber` function gets called? If yes, I would recommend using an event or callback instead.